# converting string with Apostrophes to long (not int)

Tags: python, python-2.7

how can I convert string with this string "70" (with the Apostrophes)  to long

code:

```
 gap = long(x.film_index)-   long (expected_film)
```

The error: ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '"70"'

Comment: Have you tried just stripping the aposts? `long(x.film_index.strip('"'))` ?

Comment: Also note `long` is gone in 3.x, there's not harm in using `int` in either 2.x or 3.x as in 2.x it'll automatically be converted to a `long` where needs be.

Comment: same error: 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"70"'

Comment: still doesn't help
gap = (x.film_index.strip('"'))-    (expected_film.strip('"'))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Then one of them is already an int and not a string... What does `type(x.film_index), type(expected_film)` show you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about removing the quotes first using [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)?

```
>>> x = '"70"'
>>> x
'"70"'
>>> long(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '"70"'

>>> long(x.replace('"', ''))
70L
```

Comment: Thanks I think I will use this option

Answer (score 4):

`strip` off the quote marks before converting.

```
>>> x = "\"70\""
>>> long(x.strip("\""))
70L
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to extract only digits from a given string:

```
import re
long(re.match(r'\d+', '"70"').group())
```

However, if you know that your number will be *always* surrounded with `"`s, then you can easily construct a new `int` from it without first and last chars:

```
long('"70"'.strip('"'))  # or long('"70"'.replace('"', ''))
```